# fullcalendar-railsのgemで実装するにあたり、Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_calendar' of undefinedというエラーがでます。

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

以下のコードを参考に、実装しておりました。
https://github.com/siguremon/calendarclone/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/calendar.js

但し、バージョンが古かったため、ローカルでは以下のバージョンで行っております。

ruby 2.2.2p95
rails 4.2.5

カレンダーは表示され、モーダル画面でタイトルを入力するところまではできたのですが、OKを押す際に

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_calendar' of undefined
```

というエラーが発生します。

エラー元のファイルはmoment.jsの以下の部分となっています．

```
    function locale_calendar__calendar (key, mom, now) {
        var output = this._calendar[key];      // ←エラー発生箇所
        return typeof output === 'function' ? output.call(mom, now) : output;
    }
```

moment.js は gemでいれた部分なので、私のほうで何か弄っているわけではありません。

色々と調べていると、以下が似たような症状だったため
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436574/fullcalendar-v2-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-month-of-undef

```
event.start.format()
```

```
start.format()
```

といったようにformatを入れたりしたのですが、ダメでした。

また、ダメ元で、gemの当該箇所の部分をコメントアウトしてみましたが、そうするとまた、別の箇所でエラーがでてしまったため、この方法はやめました。

```
Cannot read property '_longDateFormat' of undefined
```

外部ライブラリ(moment.js)に対するデバッグ方法がわからず、
今回の解決方法に手詰まりになっております。

どなたかご助言いただけないでしょうか。

宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/

start.unix()を使うとエラーが解消されました。ご参考まで